# Session and JavaScript Object in CefSharp Library

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp, awesomium, cefsharp.offscreen

Currently, I am working in a WPF application where we are using Awesomium tool to add web-browser but as that is already outdated we are trying to shift from Awesomium library to CefSharp library (Using CefSharpe and CefSharp.wpf Library).

At the time of transferring, I found some control like

`webControl.WebSession` (they are using to Save a reference to the page's session object)

And

`JSObject` class object using for "Represents an Object type in JavaScript"

I tried to change these two Awesomium control to CefSharpe control but I didn't get any similar working control present in Cefsharp.wpf and CefSharpe package library.
I also checked in CefSharp document as well as in google but didn't get any clear idea how can I change these two controls.

Comment: See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#javascript-integration there is no direct mapping of either class

Comment: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#need-to-knowlimitations

Comment: This should probably be two separate questions